# Updating c8y_RequiredAvailability using MQTT Templates

Tags: cumulocity

We have MQTT devices that can change how often they send data, so we want to be able to have the device change its c8y_RequiredAvailability value.

I have tried using static template 117, but that only works for the initial creation, not for updating.
I am currently trying to create a [SmartREST Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Qx5O.jpg) but I keep getting the following error:

```
50,,Error of type: ClassCastException with message: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
```

when sending the following publish:

```
800,MQTT_FX_Client3,8
```

Any ideas what I am missing?

Comment: This is not really a question regarding development. You encounter a server error and should report that to the Cumulocity support. You already took both existing approaches and neither of them seem to work.

Comment: Ok. I didn't know if there was another way to do it since the two ways I tried didn't seem to work.